# Remove one NSArray nested from array (Objective c)

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have this pattern in myArray:

```
myArray[0][0] = "28.04"
myArray[1][0] = "21.12"
myArray[2][0] = "12.33"
```

And I want to have like this:

```
myArray[0] = "28.04"
myArray[1] = "21.12"
myArray[2] = "12.33"
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a higher-order function called flatmap

```
- (NSArray *)flatMap:(id (^)(id obj))block {
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        id _obj = block(obj);
        if ([_obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            NSArray *_array = [_obj flatMap:block];
            [mutableArray addObjectsFromArray:_array];
            return;
        }
        [mutableArray addObject:_obj];
    }];
    return mutableArray;
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Perhaps you should show how to use your `flatMap` method to answer the question. And you should clarify that this method is part of an `NSArray` category.

Comment: Flatmap is a functional programming stuff, it's a general idea. Since Objective-C doesn't have this, you should implement this on your own. But it's very common among modern languages like Swift, JavaScript, C# and so on.

Comment: Refer to this url: https://medium.com/@weijentu/higher-order-functions-in-objective-c-850f6c90de30

Comment: You need to update your answer to show how to use this `flatMap` method to solve the question being asked. Otherwise this is not helpful at all. You don't even state that it's a category method on `NSArray`.